# RDP from domain workstation to non-domain workstation via VPN

Tags: windows-7, vpn, remote-desktop, domain

I am trying to RDP from a domain computer to a non-domain computer over a VPN. I created a rdp profile for a specified user (for example user name: USERX) with the option to save the password. I am able to establish the connection the first time by entering in the password. However, from that point on, whenever the RDP link is reestablished, it would state that my login details were incorrect and ask me re-type the password for COMP\USERX. Problem is, I don't have a domain called COMP and the password would fail even if reentered. The only way I can reestablish the connection is by choosing the option to login as another user.

Comment: On Windows NT, all local accounts _do_ belong to a domain, named after the machine itself and completely internal. So `HOSTNAME\Username` is actually the correct syntax.

Comment: @grawity It may be the correct syntax but the entered password fails regardless. It only works if I login using the other account option. I also noticed that when I do login using the other account option, it states the "domain: COMP" right beneath the password.